# How to add value to column using dplyr lag() based on prior row value in same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to modify a column with test values (1 or 0) based on the prior row of the same column and the value in another column. It is not a problem for one or two rows, but I need to "lead" the value for up to 50 rows which is cumbersome to code.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 3))
names(df) <- c("letter", "color", "test")
df[, 1] <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
df[1:2, 2] <- c("blue")
df[8:10, 2] <- c("green")
df[, 3] <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

df:

```
   letter color test
1       a  blue    0
2       a  blue    0
3       b  <NA>    1
4       b  <NA>    0
5       b  <NA>    0
6       b  <NA>    0
7       b  <NA>    0
8       c green    0
9       c green    0
10      c green    0
```

My actual data is rather hard to recreate for this question, but this `df` is where I'm at after the first bit of coding - I've identified that the "1" in the test column (`df[3, 3]`) is where my problem starts. I now need to "lead" the 1 in the test column until the "color" is not `NA` and the "letter" is not "b".

Code such as the following will not suffice (even though my example makes it look like it will):

```
... mutate(test = ifelse(letter == "b" & is.na(color), 1, test)
```

For my purposes, I need to use the following code to "lead" the 1:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test))
```

However, running this code will only populate the single next row:

```
   letter color test
1       a  blue    0
2       a  blue    0
3       b  <NA>    1
4       b  <NA>    1
5       b  <NA>    0
6       b  <NA>    0
7       b  <NA>    0
8       c green    0
9       c green    0
10      c green    0
```

To accomplish this, I have been writing the same `mutate` command like 50 times (running over the same column). For example:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test), 
         test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test), 
         test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test), 
         test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test), 
         test = ifelse(lag(test) == 1 & is.na(color), 1, test))
```

This returns the desired result:

```
  letter color test
1       a  blue    0
2       a  blue    0
3       b  <NA>    1
4       b  <NA>    1
5       b  <NA>    1
6       b  <NA>    1
7       b  <NA>    1
8       c green    0
9       c green    0
10      c green    0
```

But this is quite clumsy and potentially leaves the possibility open that I did not write enough duplicate `mutate` commands.

Is there a way to use `dplyr` (or another method) to accomplish this? A for loop could probably get the job done, but I'm not sure it's necessary. Additionally, I am still learning R and have not really been able to figure out the `apply` family of functions. Could an `apply` variant be used in this situation?

Comment: `Code such as the following will not suffice (even though my example makes it look like it will)`  I think it would be better to change the example so that others won't get misunderstood

Comment: Okay. I'm not really sure how to draw up a simple example that is in line with my data. I'll work on something else I guess...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly then considering your example you can achieve the end result using

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(letter, color) %>%
  mutate(test = first(test))
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(letter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), color = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("<NA>", "blue", 
"green"), class = "factor"), test = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("letter", "color", "test"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Not very clear by the OP but I think your method will fail If not the `first` but the say, second entry is 1. i.e. Try and change  `df$test[3] <- 0` and `df$test[4] <- 1`.

Comment: @Sotos agree! Seems OP needs to intervene and clarify his UC (but with the given data it should work).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm still trying to figure out a better example for what I need to accomplish. I cannot achieve this by grouping by the "letter" variable unfortunately. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You might be over complicating everything with `lag`. It seems that  by grouping by `letter` you can simply `fill` all the rest of the positions (after 1) where your color is `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(letter) %>% 
 mutate(test = replace(test, is.na(color) & test != 1, NA)) %>% 
 fill(test)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
> # Groups:   letter [3]
>    letter color  test
>     <chr> <chr> <dbl>
>  1      a  blue     0
>  2      a  blue     0
>  3      b  <NA>     1
>  4      b  <NA>     1
>  5      b  <NA>     1
>  6      b  <NA>     1
>  7      b  <NA>     1
>  8      c green     0
>  9      c green     0
> 10      c green     0
> ```

Comment: I should have used a better example - as akrun stated in his comment above. Grouping by the letter variable will not work for my data. Sorry for the confusion.